# Find the URL of the current web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

In an ASP.NET Application running from within an IIS. What is the correct way to find the URL of my application. I mean the IIS configuration, ignoring proxies, redirection and URL rewriting.

Thank you

---

I would really prefer it not to be dependent on a request...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string app = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Request.ServerVariables[ "HTTP_URL" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it should work:

```
string app = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
```

Comment: No it would give me the path on the server -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.physicalapplicationpath.aspx

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean "URL of my application"?

to get the physical app path:  `string path= HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;`

or try this if this is what you want: `string path =  System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;`

Answer (score -1):

Try this other option:

```
Uri uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
string strCompleteUrl = uri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Host + ":" + uri.Port + uri.AbsolutePath;
```